# How to display temperature in degress celsius in app

Tags: android

I have followed a tutorial on digitalphantom's website of creating a weather app.  But the problem is I don't know how to convert the temperature to show degrees celsuis.

Here is the code:

```
String YQL = String.format("select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"%s\")", location);

            String endpoint = String.format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s&format=json", Uri.encode(YQL));
```

Sorry if this question is very vague or not a lot of info, but still learning myself and hoping someone would help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't even a CS question is it?  Looks like math, and a quick google search should show you the formula.

Comment: Too funny. You are asking math formula in stackoverflow. Increase habit of using google not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius is given by

C = (F - 32) x (5/9)

The Formula to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit is given by

F = C x (9/5) + 32

found [here](http://formulas.tutorvista.com/physics/fahrenheit-to-celsius-formula.html)

Comment: The OP can search Google by themselves. By answering, you encourage posting irrelevant questions.

Comment: @Stephen Miller:  Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I think he knows now but being the rule police scare people away from the site